# WooCommerce webhooks with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, woocommerce

I am trying to integrate WooCommerce webhooks with Django but without success. I found a solution to a similar issue, but still cant make it work.

The thing is that, Woocomerce is generating this secret key automatically. I guess that I have to hard code it by myself in the admin panel ?

Also about the code bellow(solution found in the web), Django is complaining that request has no property payload. I guess that it must be data ?

```
mport base64
import hashlib
import hmac

request_sig = request.headers.get("x-wc-webhook-signature")
signature = hmac.new(<your_secret_key>.encode(), request.payload, hashlib.sha256).digest()
if hmac.compare_digest(
       request_sig.encode(), base64.b64encode(signature)
):
   return True
return False
```

```
enter code here
```